# win32 window won't show child windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-11, dwm

I'm trying to create a window with c++ winapi (`CreateWindowExW`, `RegisterClassExW`).
The window is dark, has the mica theme, and is borderless.

The window itself works fine, but when I'm trying to create any kind of child window (in this example, a button) it just won't show on the parent.

Does anyone why?

The window and button creation is as such:

```
WNDCLASSEXW wcx{};
wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);
wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcx.hInstance = nullptr;
wcx.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
wcx.lpszClassName = L"RunUIClass";
wcx.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcx.hCursor = ::LoadCursorW(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
ATOM result = ::RegisterClassExW(&wcx);

auto handle = CreateWindowExW(
            WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP | WS_EX_TOPMOST, L"RunUIClass", L"RunUI Window",
            WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - (APP_WIDTH / 2), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - (APP_HEIGHT / 2),
            APP_WIDTH, APP_HEIGHT, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, userdata
        );

auto button = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, L"Button",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
        50, 50,
        BUTTON_SIZE, BUTTON_SIZE,
        handle, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Do you get a valid window handle ?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, yes, `IsWindow` returned true

Comment: I wonder why you aren't using the [`WS_CLIPCHILDREN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) window style on the parent window. I also wonder what you're using the `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` style for. Besides, please provide a [mcve] that's actually minimal. Most of the code isn't required, and the C++ abstractions only distract from seeing the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP ` is necessary to get the window design right, without it the window is just plain white instead of dark-transparent. however I tried to remove this flag now and the button does appear, so I guess it has to do with the appearance of child windows. If I turn the `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` off than the button appears regardless of `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`. at least now i know where to look for :) also, thanks for pointing out my example. if the problem will persist, I'll upload a better one

Comment: Do you know what the `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` extended window style [actually does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/windows-with-c-high-performance-window-layering-using-the-windows-composition-engine)?

Comment: You need [Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows) to make window transparent. You may also need [DWM Blur Behind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/blur-ovw).

Comment: @yan You do not. That's **one** option. Using `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` is another option. Though, noone actually assumes that any of you *"- MSFT"* are actually in the know, so no harm done.